# How can i remove or separate the emoji (encoded in "utf-8") from a text as shown below

Tags: python, r

How can i remove or separate the emoji (encoded in "utf-8") from a text as shown below

I mean,how can i remove "\xf0\x9f\x91\x8d\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbd" from my text

```py
text="b'That new one I\xe2\x80\x99m Ikorodu is a masterpiece.Thanks for beautifying the landscape. \xf0\x9f\x91\x8d\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbdUnlike @jpoy that build banks like Prisons where human organs are harvested.'"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to define what characters you want to remove, and then loop through them, and use the "replace" function.

```
text="b'That new one I\xe2\x80\x99m Ikorodu is a masterpiece.Thanks for beautifying the landscape. \xf0\x9f\x91\x8d\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbdUnlike @jpoy that build banks like Prisons where human organs are harvested.'"
bad_chars = ['I\xe2', '\x80', '\x99m', "\xf0"] 
for i in bad_chars : 
    text = text.replace(i, '') 
text
```

Reference : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-removing-unwanted-characters-from-string/

Comment: Thanks but I have a csv file with a column text and I have alot of this bad character on each rows. This bad character was a result of  encoding my emojis to "utf-8". Can I remove all emojis encoded in bytes from csv file?

Comment: If you can upload part of the original csv here ( as csv file), then I can help you better.

Comment: thanks brother,kindly drop your email address so i can send it to your mail.